# Log4j email sending on error hanging java thread application

Tags: java, multithreading

I have a java application that has two Thread running apart from the main thread. I am using Log4j for sending email on errors.  The application is working fine with start up and sending emails on error. But the application is getting hanged after some time like 30 minutes.  Please advice.

Here is the Thread dump

> Full thread dump Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (23.3-b01 mixed
>   mode):
>
> "Attach Listener" daemon prio=10 tid=0x00007fe564001000 nid=0x76b5
>   waiting on condition [0x0000000000000000]
>
> java.lang.Thread.State: RUNNABLE
>
> "MultiThreadedHttpConnectionManager cleanup" daemon prio=10
>   tid=0x00007fe5400f9000 nid=0x6ff8 in Object.wait()
>   [0x00007fe57c414000]
>
> java.lang.Thread.State: WAITING (on object monitor)
>
> ```
> at java.lang.Object.wait(Native Method)
>
> - waiting on <0x00000000fd97cf50> (a java.lang.ref.ReferenceQueue$Lock)
>
> at java.lang.ref.ReferenceQueue.remove(ReferenceQueue.java:135)
>
> - locked <0x00000000fd97cf50> (a java.lang.ref.ReferenceQueue$Lock)
>
> at java.lang.ref.ReferenceQueue.remove(ReferenceQueue.java:151)
>
> at org.apache.commons.httpclient.MultiThreadedHttpConnectionManager$ReferenceQueueThread.run(MultiThreadedHttpConnectionManager.java:1122)
> ```
>
> "Timer-0" daemon prio=10 tid=0x00007fe540044000 nid=0x6ff7 in
>   Object.wait() [0x00007fe57c515000]
>
> java.lang.Thread.State: TIMED_WAITING (on object monitor)
>
> ```
> at java.lang.Object.wait(Native Method)
>
> - waiting on <0x00000000fda732b8> (a java.util.TaskQueue)
>
> at java.util.TimerThread.mainLoop(Timer.java:552)
>
> - locked <0x00000000fda732b8> (a java.util.TaskQueue)
>
> at java.util.TimerThread.run(Timer.java:505)
> ```
>
> "BBMONITOR" prio=10 tid=0x00007fe5848a0000 nid=0x6ff6 waiting for
>   monitor entry [0x00007fe57c616000]
>
> java.lang.Thread.State: BLOCKED (on object monitor)
>
> ```
> at org.apache.log4j.AppenderSkeleton.doAppend(AppenderSkeleton.java:247)
>
> - waiting to lock <0x00000000fd964fb8> (a org.apache.log4j.net.SMTPAppender)
>
> at org.apache.log4j.helpers.AppenderAttachableImpl.appendLoopOnAppenders(AppenderAttachableImpl.java:67)
>
> at org.apache.log4j.Category.callAppenders(Category.java:218)
>
> at org.apache.log4j.Category.forcedLog(Category.java:587)
>
> at org.apache.log4j.Category.info(Category.java:856)
>
> at com.shaklee.processor.ShakleeRNTUserProfileBBMonitor.bb_notify(ShakleeRNTUserProfileBBMonitor.java:94)
>
> at com.shaklee.processor.ShakleeRNTUserProfileBBMonitor.bbmonitor(ShakleeRNTUserProfileBBMonitor.java:124)
>
> at com.shaklee.processor.ShakleeRNTUserProfileBBMonitor.run(ShakleeRNTUserProfileBBMonitor.java:144)
>
> at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:722)
> ```
>
> "PROFILEPROCESSOR" prio=10 tid=0x00007fe584922000 nid=0x6ff5 runnable
>   [0x00007fe57c716000]
>
> java.lang.Thread.State: RUNNABLE
>
> ```
> at java.net.SocketInputStream.socketRead0(Native Method)
>
> at java.net.SocketInputStream.read(SocketInputStream.java:150)
>
> at java.net.SocketInputStream.read(SocketInputStream.java:121)
>
> at com.sun.mail.util.TraceInputStream.read(TraceInputStream.java:110)
>
> at java.io.BufferedInputStream.fill(BufferedInputStream.java:235)
>
> at java.io.BufferedInputStream.read(BufferedInputStream.java:254)
>
> - locked <0x00000000ecea5c58> (a java.io.BufferedInputStream)
>
> at com.sun.mail.util.LineInputStream.readLine(LineInputStream.java:88)
>
> at com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPTransport.readServerResponse(SMTPTransport.java:1589)
>
> at com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPTransport.close(SMTPTransport.java:698)
>
> - locked <0x00000000ecea2698> (a com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPTransport)
>
> at javax.mail.Transport.send0(Transport.java:191)
>
> at javax.mail.Transport.send(Transport.java:118)
>
> at org.apache.log4j.net.SMTPAppender.sendBuffer(SMTPAppender.java:300)
>
> at org.apache.log4j.net.SMTPAppender.append(SMTPAppender.java:181)
>
> at org.apache.log4j.AppenderSkeleton.doAppend(AppenderSkeleton.java:286)
>
> - locked <0x00000000fd964fb8> (a org.apache.log4j.net.SMTPAppender)
>
> at org.apache.log4j.helpers.AppenderAttachableImpl.appendLoopOnAppenders(AppenderAttachableImpl.java:67)
>
> at org.apache.log4j.Category.callAppenders(Category.java:218)
>
> at org.apache.log4j.Category.forcedLog(Category.java:587)
>
> at org.apache.log4j.Category.error(Category.java:406)
>
> at com.shaklee.processor.UserProfileFileProcessor.processFile(UserProfileFileProcessor.java:96)
>
> - locked <0x00000000fda70e70> (a java.lang.Object)
>
> at com.shaklee.processor.UserProfileFileProcessor.run(UserProfileFileProcessor.java:58)
> ```
>
> "Thread-1" daemon prio=10 tid=0x00007fe584d6f800 nid=0x6ff4 runnable
>   [0x00007fe57c818000]
>
> java.lang.Thread.State: RUNNABLE
>
> ```
> at sun.nio.fs.LinuxWatchService.poll(Native Method)
>
> at sun.nio.fs.LinuxWatchService.access$600(LinuxWatchService.java:47)
>
> at sun.nio.fs.LinuxWatchService$Poller.run(LinuxWatchService.java:311)
>
> at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:722)
> ```
>
> "Service Thread" daemon prio=10 tid=0x00007fe584171800 nid=0x6ff0
>   runnable [0x0000000000000000]
>
> java.lang.Thread.State: RUNNABLE
>
> "C2 CompilerThread1" daemon prio=10 tid=0x00007fe58416f000 nid=0x6fef
>   waiting on condition [0x0000000000000000]
>
> java.lang.Thread.State: RUNNABLE
>
> "C2 CompilerThread0" daemon prio=10 tid=0x00007fe58416c800 nid=0x6fee
>   waiting on condition [0x0000000000000000]
>
> java.lang.Thread.State: RUNNABLE
>
> "Signal Dispatcher" daemon prio=10 tid=0x00007fe58416a000 nid=0x6fed
>   runnable [0x0000000000000000]
>
> java.lang.Thread.State: RUNNABLE
>
> "Finalizer" daemon prio=10 tid=0x00007fe58411d000 nid=0x6fec in
>   Object.wait() [0x00007fe57d44b000]
>
> java.lang.Thread.State: WAITING (on object monitor)
>
> ```
> at java.lang.Object.wait(Native Method)
>
> - waiting on <0x00000000fdde4588> (a java.lang.ref.ReferenceQueue$Lock)
>
> at java.lang.ref.ReferenceQueue.remove(ReferenceQueue.java:135)
>
> - locked <0x00000000fdde4588> (a java.lang.ref.ReferenceQueue$Lock)
>
> at java.lang.ref.ReferenceQueue.remove(ReferenceQueue.java:151)
>
> at java.lang.ref.Finalizer$FinalizerThread.run(Finalizer.java:177)
> ```
>
> "Reference Handler" daemon prio=10 tid=0x00007fe58411b000 nid=0x6feb
>   in Object.wait() [0x00007fe57d54c000]
>
> java.lang.Thread.State: WAITING (on object monitor)
>
> ```
> at java.lang.Object.wait(Native Method)
>
> - waiting on <0x00000000fdde43a0> (a java.lang.ref.Reference$Lock)
>
> at java.lang.Object.wait(Object.java:503)
>
> at java.lang.ref.Reference$ReferenceHandler.run(Reference.java:133)
>
> - locked <0x00000000fdde43a0> (a java.lang.ref.Reference$Lock)
> ```
>
> "main" prio=10 tid=0x00007fe584007800 nid=0x6fe7 waiting on condition
>   [0x00007fe5884e1000]
>
> java.lang.Thread.State: WAITING (parking)
>
> ```
> at sun.misc.Unsafe.park(Native Method)
>
> - parking to wait for  <0x00000000c4c01a90> (a java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer$ConditionObject)
>
> at java.util.concurrent.locks.LockSupport.park(LockSupport.java:186)
>
> at java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer$ConditionObject.await(AbstractQueuedSynchronizer.java:2043)
>
> at java.util.concurrent.LinkedBlockingDeque.takeFirst(LinkedBlockingDeque.java:489)
>
> at java.util.concurrent.LinkedBlockingDeque.take(LinkedBlockingDeque.java:678)
>
> at sun.nio.fs.AbstractWatchService.take(AbstractWatchService.java:118)
>
> at com.shaklee.RNTUserProfile.processIncomingFiles(RNTUserProfile.java:140)
>
> at com.shaklee.RNTUserProfile.main(RNTUserProfile.java:74)
>
> at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
>
> at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
>
> at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
>
> at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:601)
>
> at com.simontuffs.onejar.Boot.run(Boot.java:342)
>
> at com.simontuffs.onejar.Boot.main(Boot.java:168)
> ```
>
> "VM Thread" prio=10 tid=0x00007fe584113800 nid=0x6fea runnable
>
> "GC task thread#0 (ParallelGC)" prio=10 tid=0x00007fe584015000
>   nid=0x6fe8 runnable
>
> "GC task thread#1 (ParallelGC)" prio=10 tid=0x00007fe584017000
>   nid=0x6fe9 runnable
>
> "VM Periodic Task Thread" prio=10 tid=0x00007fe584174800 nid=0x6ff1
>   waiting on condition

JNI global references: 223

Thanks,
JK